# when call syscall.NetlinkRIB , fd = 0

Tags: sockets, system-calls

call net.InterfaceByName method, but stuck, and the Recvfrom method recelve args , include fd is 0

expect when create socket success , fd not equal 0 ,
and sometime when call net.InterfaceByName  fd type netlink, fd = 12, but has a goroutine use fd = 12 receive msg

above  goroutine stuck at net.InterfaceByName

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HvADS.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LaBd7.png)

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/238704)